# Ada GPS editor crashes when pasting in text

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps

While editing this package body:

```
package body ai is

   type Possible_Boards is

end ai;
```

GPS crashes when pasting the following code after the **is**:

```
    let bestMoves = [
        0x1160:1,
        0x1205:0,
        0x1304:0,
        0x1340:0,
        0x1403:0,
        0x1430:0,
        0x1502:0,
        0x1520:0,
        0x1601:0,
        0x1610:1,
        0x1700:0,
        0x2222:0,
        0x2330:0,
        0x2420:0,
        0x2510:0,
        0x3140:1,
        0x3203:0,
        0x3230:0,
        0x3320:0,
        0x4103:0,
        0x4130:1,
        0x4220:0,
        0x5120:1,
        0x6101:0,
        0x6110:1 ];
```

Obviously, this isn't Ada code, but crashing GPS doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: Which version and source/distribution of GNAT GPS shows this behaviour?

Comment: No problems with the Darwin (macOS) versions, either 2017 or 2018.

Comment: Use the version of the GPS in the Community Edition that can be downloaded here: https://www.adacore.com/download. The GPS is known for its stability. The only way I know of that one can crash the GPS is if one uses the debugger and is stepping through ones code a lot.

Comment: Here's what's on my Help About window.

GPS 2018 (20180528) hosted on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
GNAT 4.6

the GNAT Programming Studio

(c) 2001-2018 AdaCore

Comment: GPS version/details should appear in your question. By the way, this would rather be a ticket for Adacore than a stack overflow question.